# requests-html not finding page element

Tags: python, cookies, web-scraping, python-requests-html

So I'm trying to navigate to this url: `https://www.instacart.com/store/wegmans/search_v3/horizon%201%25`
and scrape data from the div with the class `item-name item-row`.  There are two main problems though, the first is that instacart.com requires a login before you can get to that url, and the second is that most of the page is generated with javascript.

I believe I've solved the first problem because my `session.post(...)` gets a 200 response code.  I'm also pretty sure that `r.html.render()` is supposed to solve the second problem by rendering the javascript generated html before I scrape it.  Unfortunately, the last line in my code is only returning an empty list, despite the fact that selenium had no problem getting this element.  Does anyone know why this isn't workng?

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'}
session = HTMLSession()
res1 = session.get('http://www.instacart.com', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res1.content, 'html.parser')
token = soup.find('meta', {'name': 'csrf-token'}).get('content')
data = {"user": {"email": "alexanderjbusch@gmail.com", "password": "password"},
        "authenticity_token": token}
response = session.post('https://www.instacart.com/accounts/login', headers=headers, data=data)
print(response)
r = session.get("https://www.instacart.com/store/wegmans/search_v3/horizon%201%25", headers=headers)
r.html.render()
print(r.html.xpath("//div[@class='item-name item-row']"))
```

Comment: Once you logged in, try using [this link](https://www.instacart.com/v3/retailers/159/module_data/dynamic_item_lists/cart_starters/storefront_canonical?origin_source_type=store_root_department&tracking.page_view_id=b974d56d-eaa4-4ce2-9474-ada4723fc7dc&source=web&cache_key=df535d-6863-f-1cd&per=30) to get the items you look for.

Comment: I don't understand.  What is that link for?  How can I use it to get the item data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After logging in using requests module and BeautifulSoup, you can make use of the link I've already suggested in the comment to parse the required data available within json. The following script should get you name, quantity, price and a link to the concerning product. You can only get 21 product using the script below. There is an option for pagination within this json content. You can get all of the products by playing around with that pagination.

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseurl = 'https://www.instacart.com/store/'
data_url = "https://www.instacart.com/v3/retailers/159/module_data/dynamic_item_lists/cart_starters/storefront_canonical?origin_source_type=store_root_department&tracking.page_view_id=b974d56d-eaa4-4ce2-9474-ada4723fc7dc&source=web&cache_key=df535d-6863-f-1cd&per=30"

data = {"user": {"email": "alexanderjbusch@gmail.com", "password": "password"},
        "authenticity_token": ""}
headers = {
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}
with requests.Session() as s:

    res = s.get('https://www.instacart.com/',headers={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    token = soup.select_one("[name='csrf-token']").get('content')

    data["authenticity_token"] = token

    s.post("https://www.instacart.com/accounts/login",json=data,headers=headers)
    resp = s.get(data_url, headers=headers)

    for item in resp.json()['module_data']['items']:
        name = item['name']
        quantity = item['size']
        price = item['pricing']['price']
        product_page = baseurl + item['click_action']['data']['container']['path']
        print(f'{name}\n{quantity}\n{price}\n{product_page}\n')
```

Partial output:

```
SB Whole Milk
1 gal
$3.90
https://www.instacart.com/store/items/item_147511418

Banana
At $0.69/lb
$0.26
https://www.instacart.com/store/items/item_147559922

Yellow Onion
At $1.14/lb
$0.82
https://www.instacart.com/store/items/item_147560764
```

Comment: Ok, so this is a huge step in the right direction, but I have two questions before I mark this as the answer.  First, how did you find this url, so I know how to find in the future if I want to scrape other similar websites?  second, how do I get data for specific items from specific stores?  For example, horizon 1% milk from wegmans?  Do I change the base url or something else?

Comment: Before attempting to scrape any website, you need to learn how the requests are being sent which you can find out by opening chrome dev tools. Once you open the dev tools, find the network tab then select xhr tab and then reload the page. When the page is reloaded you can see several urls in the left pane doing different network activity. Just choose the right url containing the data you want and then click on it. Now you should see lots of info in the right pane about that url. You only need to replace the desired url with the data_url.

Comment: Btw, if the url you wanna put there is of different json structures then you need to modify the script from `for loop` to the end to satisfy your need. Thanks.